# SSIS Error : 0xC00160AE - Access is denied

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I don't think this question has been answered, apologies if I've missed a thread.

In short, I've performed a vanilla install of a SQL 2012 and SSIS on my local machine.
I've configured SSIS to run with the NT AUTHORITY\Local Service account (also tried my local login), and am running SSMS under my local login (I'm a local admin).
SQL instance is running as NT Service\MSSQLSERVER.

I can access Integration Services in the object explorer and run packages using the GUI. However, when calling from code, I get the following:

> Could not load package "\MSDB\FileLoad\CustomerMaster_Customer"
>   because of error 0xC00160AE. Description: Connecting to the
>   Integration Services service on the computer "UKLT-RHE-1" failed with
>   the following error: "Access is denied."
>
> By default, only administrators have access to the Integration
>   Services service. On Windows Vista and later, the process must be
>   running with administrative privileges in order to connect to the
>   Integration Services service. See the help topic for information on
>   how to configure access to the service.

Any help is muchly appreciated!!

Thanks in advance,

Rich

Comment: I'd like to pin onto this that this exact error will also get thrown if you've misspelled the name of your integration services instance...

Answer (score 10):

Fixed it..!

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213130.aspx

N.B. Step 6 - Repeat steps 4 - 5 for **Access Permissions**.

HTH someone!

Answer (score 9):

Just in case the page indicated by @richhemmings is not available.

> To grant access to the Integration Services service
>
> 1.Run Dcomcnfg.exe. Dcomcnfg.exe provides a user interface for modifying certain settings in the registry.
>
> 2.In the Component Services dialog, expand the Component Services > Computers > My Computer > DCOM Config node.
>
> 3.Right-click Microsoft SQL Server Integration Services 11.0, and then click Properties.
>
> 4.On the Security tab, click Edit in the Launch and Activation Permissions area.
>
> 5.Add users and assign appropriate permissions, and then click Ok.
>
> 6.Repeat steps 4 - 5 for Access Permissions.
>
> 7.Restart SQL Server Management Studio.
>
> 8.Restart the Integration Services Service.

Comment: And who would have thought, the page indicated by @richhemmings *is* not available.

Answer (score 1):

The error message says "By default, only administrators have access to the Integration Services service."
Therefore you run SQL Server Management Studio as administrator.

https://youtu.be/WyKHStfz0uk